# Sbt add to PluginClassPath from consuming project.

Tags: sbt, osgi, bnd

I'm using sbt-osgi built from git and I'm trying to load a bnd plugin jar via a bnd header.

additionalHeaders := Map(
  "-buildpath" -> "org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation.jar",
  "-plugin"  -> "org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.plugin.bnd.AnnotationPlugin")

Is there anyway for me to jack into the sbt classloaders or am I going to have to fork sbt-osgi ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be quite simple, the `-buildpath` flag is not needed at all. You just need to add a libraryDependency to whatever libs you need on the classpath in `plugins.sbt` just using the `libraryDependencies` setting key. voila.